# Length of input parameter greater than format mask To_CHAR

Tags: sql, oracle, to-char

While executing the below query, the result is #.

Can someone explain to me the reason?

```
select to_char(1228.0000,'$999.9999') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Length of 1228 exceeds length of 999. The following works:

- `select to_char(1228.0000,'$9999.9999') from dual; -- $1228.0000`
- `select to_char(122.0000,'$999.9999') from dual;   --  $122.0000`